# Displaying Local Images, Movies and Sounds in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have developed a flash card application to help people learn languages in C# as a Windows application.

The problem is now that this system must be available on more operating systems rather than just windows.

So I am thinking if I could replecate this in HTML + JavaScript.

As it is a program for learning languages it repeats audios, videos and images many times. It may need to access thousands of images, movies and sounds. This is no problem of course with a windows application. Of course it could download these files every time it has to play them but this would end up being very download intesive and slow. So the files must be stored locally.

So would it be possible to create such a system in HTML + JavaScript? Or are there too many limitations on accessing local files. I was hoping it would work on win/mac/android/ios.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you read this tutorial everything will be clear ;)

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Thanks I had a read of this one before. It seems that you would have to drag the folder into the webpage or use an open file dialog each time to give it access to the files in a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course...It will surely work and on all operating systems...

In HTML there are tags already available for embedding audios,videos and images..

put `<audio>`  and `<video>` tags for embedding sounds and clips like this:

```
<audio src="xyz.mp3></audi>
```

same for video and images... you can set their positions, height, width by adjusting attributes..you can use javascript for generating events.

following link may help you:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp

Comment: Yep thanks for your time, but will this work for local files? Will the .html file have to be in the same folder as the files? Ie stored locally too?

Comment: You should copy your audio and video files in the same folder that contains .html pages...However..it is not compulsory...you can include full path like: '<audio src="d:\movies\die hard 4.0">'</audio>...If this file is on web resources than you can include url like: '<audio src=http://www.movies.com/die hard 4.0>'...However, If file isn't on web resources..then it will be easy to keep them in same folder.